# A good way to display large images online

Tags: optimization, google-maps

I need to show an image that is 4000x6000 px. What are your experiences with displaying large images online?

My initial idea was to use the [GMap cutter](http://www.casa.ucl.ac.uk/software/gmapcreator.asp) and the Google Maps API to show the image. GMap Cutter takes an image and cuts it appropriately for use as a google map. My problem with approach is that the image will be changing often, and so I'll need to re-cut the image often. GMap Cutter doesn't have a command-line version, so I can't write a cron job for this...I'll need to do it manually every hour or so. Is there a better option for doing this?

Or any other solutions I can consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GDAL2Tiles](http://www.klokan.cz/projects/gdal2tiles/) utility, which is a part of [GDAL](https://gdal.org/), can be easily automated via command-line.

There is also a GUI for it, called [MapTiler](https://www.maptiler.com/).  They have some info on running GDAL2Tiles [here](http://help.maptiler.org/betatest/).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend slicing it up with ImageMagick. It allows cropping via a view port and is fairly configurable. In addition it works fairly well from a Linux/Windows command prompt (or within Perl,PHP or Python using exec).

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/

Here's the documentation for the actual tile crop functionality.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

With options to crop using gravity, the ability to adjust the size/quality of the output image and support for virtually every common image format ImageMagick should get you done.

Comment: I would normally do something like this because I do like ImageMagick, but Google Maps uses a complex tile system that I'm hoping to avoid getting dirty with.

Answer (score 2):

[zoom.it](http://zoom.it/) is a relatively straight forward way to  display large images online.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/Murtnowski/GMap-JSlicer

```
slicer = new JSlicer(document.getElementById('map'), 'myImage.png');
slicer.init();
```

It's super simple.

You can see if in the wild at http://gvgmaps.com/ffvi/

If you need to update the map just change `myImage.png` then reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollable div/iframe/pop up window?

Could use something like Mootools Scrollable to scroll the image around easily?

Or are you more worried about downloading an image that size in one go?

Comment: Exactly -- I'm concerned about bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

how about using something like this:

http://www.zoomify.com/

Comment: I still can't automate it unless I buy the enterprise version for $795 :(